# Ubuntu Phone problems with text and USB/Bluetooth connection

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, phone

I have the BQ Aquaris E5 with Ubuntu 15.04 (r5). 
I want to give Ubuntu OS a 5* rating but I'm a bit annoyed with a few missing features...Have the following been sorted out yet?

1) Group text messages, will we be able to use that feature after the next update?

2) Picture & Video (MMS) text messages, same again, when will it be sorted?

3) The ability to transfer music, photos & videos directly from PC to Phone without having to use cloud services.

I could do file transfers via USB from my Win 7 PC (before the latest update on 03/09/15) but now it doesn't work. I have tried Bluetooth and USB to PCs/Laptops with Ubuntu, Kubuntu, Mint, Win 7 & Win 10 but still no joy. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can transfer files using scp. This works when you connect to your phone with a usb (developer mode enabled) or network connection. Also There is an app called WiFi-transfer (I did not test it, but it should enable file transfer via wifi)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same phone and I checked a few things to answer your questions:

1. You can send a text message to several people. Just start typing the first name, select it from the dropdown list and then type the
   second name. Also, you could use telegram.
2. When you write a text message, there is a small camera icon at the left of the text input field. You can use this to add pictures to the message.
3. If you connect your phone to your computer via USB (you have to enable the developer mode in the settings) you can use the 'phablet tools' to connect via ssh and transfer files using `scp`. This should also work via network. You can also take a look at an app called WiFi-transfer. This enables file transfer in the WiFi using ftp.

Comment: Thanks for your input Wayne_Yux. 
After a recent update on my Win10 laptop, I can now connect via USB.
I have to try it on my Mint PC, using your suggested developer mode, by the way, where do I find the developer mode options in settings?

As for the text messaging, I have obviously ensured that my service provider has switched on the MMS options but even after doing what you suggested, still no joy.
I also don't want to use Telegram...any ideas?

Comment: You can find the developer mode in "System Settings" -> "Info about the Phone" (might be called a bit different - I translated the name to English). For the messages: I am sorry, but I can't help you out there...

Comment: Switched off 'Enable MMS group Chat' in the message settings, now I can send group text messages.